# How to extract a data frame from a messy String?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got a dataset that has been revised before its release. However, its accessory codes had not been revised and now faces this error.
The code expects a data frame explaining the features of 255 homes, though the item is just a messy string that has no exact delimiter to convert it!

I showed the error, the types of the items in the new dataset and the content of the string in this ***[picture][1]***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way, but I use this trick to get dataframes to work with from poorly formatted SO questions.

Print the string (to let `print` take care of things like return characters, `'\n'`), then select-all and copy it.  Then use:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard("\s\s+")
```

Sometimes I have to manually adjust the spacing a little bit between a few column names for it to work correctly, but it is unreasonably effective.

Comment: It is a sufficiently different question that you can post it separately, in my opinion.  Just remember to be specific and detailed as you were in this post. Good luck!